# Is it possible to make ffmpeg faster while compressing the video using hardware acceleration? Intel GPU

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to compress my mxf file sized with 58GB to mp4 file in order to get smaller file. By the way I need to protect 4 of 5 streams(only videos) in my original mxf file. It takes 1 hour to compress and I am using a command like below.

I tried some commands and hardware accelerator option.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -hwaccel qsv -i filename.mxf -map 0.0 -map 0.1 -map 0.2 -map 0.3 -map 0.4 -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast outputfile.mp4
```

Is there any option that I can make it faster and smaller size? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gpu accelerated video processing with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510765/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Please read the wiki here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Comment: @slhck thanks for your reply. Actually I have read the manual and the command is generated from there. But I doubt that I do it right way, because I want to make it much faster to use in java program.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread that. So your real question is whether it can get any faster than the command you have tried? I don't think so. "1 hour to compress" is hard to interpret if we don't know the length of the video and the hardware. But there aren't any other options for QSV to improve the speed, I'm afraid.