# Video Converter that support GPU acceleration and command line

Tags: command-line, automation, video-conversion

Is there any paid/licensed video converter that support GPU acceleration and command line  features? I need the command line for automation purpose and GPU acceleration to convert the video in 4K in commercial way.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few. Have you tried looking anywhere ? notably `ffmpeg` and `vlc`

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510765/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Yeah both are working actually. But I forgot to mentioned that I need the paid/licensed software as I am going to use it in commercial environment.

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect that ? Can you please also elaborate a bit more on your needs ?

Comment: I need to automate the process of video conversion. The conversion need to be done by using GPU not CPU. As I am going to use that in industry the software must  be the paid/licensed version as to avoid any legal issue. Hope that you understand. Sorry for my bad english